# Can a court award percentage of revenue as copyright infringement remedy?

Tags: copyright, remedies

If someone infringes my copyright and has been using my software to run their profitable business for years – e.g., a tariff company has been using my tariff collection software – can I specifically request that damages include a portion of revenue collected via the use of my IP? If so on what grounds?

Comment: How do you know that there is infringement? Are you saying that they used it without permission, or that they acquired it illegally?

Comment: @user6726 - Do the answers to your questions inform potential answers to the original question?  I.e., need one characterize the nature of infringement to know what remedies are available in court?

Comment: Never mind: I was thinking that violation of the EULA is distinct from using a pirated copy, but I take it back.

Answer (score 2):

Under [17 USC 504(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/504),

> The copyright owner is entitled to recover the actual damages suffered
>   by him or her as a result of the infringement, and *any profits of the
>   infringer that are attributable to the infringement* and are not taken
>   into account in computing the actual damages.

Plaintiff has to establish gross revenues, then defendant has to establish deductibles "the elements of profit attributable to factors other than the copyrighted work". Under UK law, the [2006 Intellectual Property Regulation](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2006/1028/pdfs/uksi_20061028_en.pdf), this would also fall under the category of damages and as specifies in 3(2)(a)(i) includes

> the negative economic consequences, including any lost profits, which
>   the claimant has suffered, *and any unfair profits made by the
>   defendant*